# Open link in new tab when user clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a jQuery script that opens a specific url in a new tab if the user clicks somewhere (no matter where). After that, the user should be able to click anywhere without getting a new tab at every click again.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to create such a script, and therefore I would appreciate all your answears :)

Comment: I don't like the idea of this. It sounds like you're going to spam the user with ads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the .one() event like

```
$(window).one('click', function() {
 var url = "http://google.com";
 window.open(url, "_blank");
 })
```

`_blank` in window.open() is used to open the link in a new tab.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/4anfvxsm/)

Refer to following links for documentation on [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) and [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(window).one('click', function() {
   var url = "http://google.com";
   window.open(url, "_blank");
 })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).